# Is Rebecca Romijn/Jennifer Lawrence Mystique's "natural" human form?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past, x-men-first-class

Throughout the *X-Men* film franchise, Mystique has a form that she uses as a "default" human appearance, as portrayed by Rebecca Romijn and later (earlier?) Jennifer Lawrence.

[image: Smurf woman and non-smurf woman]

Is this form "natural" to her? If she was a non-mutant, would she appear this way? If she just wanted to form a human appearance without thinking about it, would it be this form?

Or is this form entirely constructed? Is this the form she consciously designs and creates because she likes it the most?

This question pertains to the film continuity only.

Comment: Mystique made a big deal about wanting to exist in her natural blue form in First Class, and yet since Jennifer Lawrence got popular she doesn't seem to care anymore. Funny that.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by her "natural" form.

As far as we can tell, the blue spiky look is Mystique's "normal" appearance as a mutant; every other form is something she has to intentionally affect. (We see this, for example, when she is knocked out and her shapeshifting ends, this is the form she takes.)

However, it seems likely that her "usual" human form is, in fact, her natural appearance pre-mutation. We can see this in the third *X-Men* movie, *X-Men: Last Stand*. In this movie, Mystique is "cured" of her mutation. Once her mutation is deactivated, she reverts to her human look, which is just Rebecca Romijn's normal appearance, for the remainder of the movie.

[image: Mystique Cured]

Comment: Besides the new one, that's the one *X-Men* movie I haven't seen. It's still probably not worth watching.

Comment: @RogueJedi And by new one you mean Deadpool of course :D

Comment: This would imply that Mystique's default human form, a blonde, is *not* what she would look like without mutation.

Comment: She has dyed her real hair black, obviously. Humans can do that.

Comment: @kevin No, *Apocalypse*.

Comment: @RogueJedi So far it's the only movie with the Phoenix Force being wielded (by Jean) so Last Stand is worth seeing from a universe completionist POV, at the very least.